# Puma gives me an `allocator undefined for Proc` error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, application-server

Here's my /config/puma.rb file:

```
path = Dir.pwd + "/tmp/puma/"

threads 0,20
environment "production"
daemonize true

bind  "unix://" + path + "socket/puma.sock"
pidfile path + "pid/puma.pid"
state_path path + "pid/puma.state"
```

And here's my terminal output when trying to use pumactl:

```
jinx@ubuntu:~/Documents/alpha$ pumactl -F config/puma.rb start
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 2.6.0, codename: Pantsuit Party
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 20
* Environment: production
* Listening on unix:///home/jinx/Documents/alpha/tmp/puma/socket/puma.sock
There is already a server bound to: /home/jinx/Documents/alpha/tmp/puma/socket/puma.sock
jinx@ubuntu:~/Documents/alpha$ pumactl -F config/puma.rb status
allocator undefined for Proc
jinx@ubuntu:~/Documents/alpha$ pumactl -F config/puma.rb stats
allocator undefined for Proc
jinx@ubuntu:~/Documents/alpha$ pumactl -F config/puma.rb stop
allocator undefined for Proc
jinx@ubuntu:~/Documents/alpha$ pumactl -F config/puma.rb foo
Invalid command: foo
```

What does this error mean? How can I use pumactl to start and stop the application server instance?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to unexpected configuration in the puma state file.

In my case an errant `lowlevel_error_handler` configuration settings:

```
:lowlevel_error_handler: !ruby/object:Proc {}
```

Removing that line allowed me to interface `pumactl` again. I would suspect that looking for a line with `!ruby/object:Proc {}` or similar would lead you to the cause of the error message.

It is unclear what actually causes this error - with the Puma issue tracker saying this has been fixed in multiple issues.